# Integer array in assembler

Tags: arrays, assembly, avr

So i want to know how one would declare and access an array in assebly language? E.g. declare an array of maybe 10 integers and either find the biggest number or add up the sum. I tried to find similar posts but I can't really tell much from them, as they do not explain anything.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_arrays.htm

Comment: _Which_ assembly language? There are many different CPU architectures, and for each of those there are often several different assemblers with slightly sifferent syntax.

Answer (score 1):

An array in assembler is created the same way as you would a normal variable.

On the stack:

```
push rbp
mov rbp, rsp
sub rsp, 4 ; size of int
; variable in [rbp-4]
mov rsp, rbp
pop rbp
```

On the heap:

```
mov edi, 4 ; size of int
call malloc
; variable in [rax]
mov rdi, rax
call free
```

Or global:

```
; variable in [var]
section .data
var: dd 0
```

Finding the biggest number or adding up the sum is not as easy in assembly as it is in other languages, there are no loops, there are no if statements, you'll have to construct these yourself using conditional jumps.

Comment: _"not an easy task"_ — actually these are one of the most trivial things to do. But, indeed, there may be little benefit in writing it in assembly, other than to learn.

Comment: @Ruslan *"Easier"* does not mean *"Easy"*, judging by the question the OP has little to none experience with assembly and writing such an algorithm will probably be difficult.

Comment: The algorithm is trivial.  The *implementation* in asm is also easy if you know assembly.  Doing it *efficiently* requires more knowledge; e.g. SSE2 is baseline for x86-64 (which you used for this answer), so an efficient array sum would use `paddd`  to work on 16 byte vectors.  Also: "better code than *any* human will ever write?"  Seriously?  How do you think compiler developers test / improve compilers?  By knowing what's efficient and teaching the compiler tricks.  Over a small scale (like a single loop) humans that have read https://agner.org/optimize/ can often beat compilers.

Comment: BTW, why did you reserve 8 bytes of space in `.data` vs. 4 bytes on the stack?  Also, no x86-64 calling conventions take args on the stack, so `push 4` before calling malloc is not useful.  For x86-64 System V (which MacOS uses), you want `mov edi, 4`.  Windows uses a different calling convention than Mac/Linux, but you must be on MacOS because only it uses leading `_` on symbol names in 64-bit mode.  Linux and Windows would both use `call malloc`.  (let me know when you fix that so I can remove my downvote.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I admit I should have spent more time on this answer. All of it was from memory and I should have checked it before posting, though I figured it was good enough to provide a proof of concept. The comment regarding compiler optimization was supposed to be a joke but did not come out right at all due to English not being my native language. All of that said I did my best to correct the answer. TLDR; Fixed.

Comment: Yup, that's better.  Still generally not a good idea to answer at all when the question is so under-specified (e.g. this might be about MIPS code running in the MARS simulator, where there is no `malloc` library function, just a "system call".)  Assuming x86-64 Linux is a big assumption.  (Windows would pass the arg to malloc in RCX, MacOS would have a leading underscore.  Not sure what *BSD does.)

Answer (score 0):

Okay thank you all for your input, I finally managed to do it. Here is my code for those who are interested:

AVR architecture:

```
;Declare variables
.dseg
.def num = R16
.def XL = R26
.def XH = R27
.def highest = R17
.def zero = R0
.def count = R18
ldi count, 11

;Initialize array with 10 values
.cseg

;Set register X to point to memory address space 0x0100
ldi XL, 0x09        ;Initialize lower byte of register X to 0x00
ldi XH, 0x01        ;Initialize higher byte of register X to 0x01

ldi num, 1          ;Set value to store in array
st X+, num          ;Store value in array and increment address to point to the next index
ldi num, 2
st X+, num
ldi num, 3
st X+, num
ldi num, 4
st X+, num
ldi num, 5
st X+, num
ldi num, 6
st X+, num
ldi num, 7
st X+, num
ldi num, 8
st X+, num
ldi num, 9
st X+, num
ldi num, 10
st X+, num

;Search for the highest number in the array

;Set register to point at first index in array again
ldi XL, 0x00
ldi XH, 0x01

HIGHEST:
ld num, X+          ;Set result to first value in array and increment index
dec count           ;Decrement counter
cp num, highest     ;Compare value with result
brsh ISBIGGER       ;If value is bigger than result set value as the new result
cp zero, count      ;Check if counter is zero
brne HIGHEST        ;If not repeat routine

END:
rjmp END

ISBIGGER:
mov highest, num    ;Set value as new result
jmp HIGHEST         ;Return to routine
```

Comment: Is that AVR?  Tag your question with the architecture.

Comment: Gotta say, though ... *"that's what **C** is for!"*  I never write "straight assembler."  All the assembly-code I need fits nicely in an `asm{...}` block.

Comment: I said *tag*, and *question*.  Fixed it for you.